# Tags for "Ubuntu installed over my Windows partition, how do I recover it?" type questions

Tags: discussion

There are many questions of the form *"Ubuntu installed over my (Windows) partition, how do I recover it?"*.  Most are already tagged as some combination of "data-recovery" and/or "system-installation" and/or "partitioning". Quite often all three are used at once. So I have been tagged the problems with all three tags ("data-recovery" and "system-installation" and "partitioning").

@Braiam [pointed out](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254239/lost-windows-xp-data-by-installing-12-04-can-i-recover-it?noredirect=1#comment625838_254239) that these tags are not accurate:

> the "system-installation" tag is for the process of installing ubuntu
>   only. Do not use if the problem is post-installation. And partitioning
>   is for questions about the process of creating, editing or removing
>   partitions.

So what should they all be tagged as? Just "data-recovery"? It would seem quite useful to have some combination of tags like [partitioning+data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/partitioning+data-recovery?sort=newest&pagesize=50) that reflects this particular problem, since it is quite common (I count 40 questions since start of April 2014)?

Comment: related: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/9193/169736 about this I only say that unless your goal is recovering the partition itself and not the data contained, you shouldn't use the partitioning tag.

Comment: Doesn't the question "How can I recover my partition" really mean "How do I recover my data"? The user isn't literally wanting to recover a particular partition layout, what they want is to recover their data. Would "partitions" be better than "partitioning"? Would tag "ubiquity" apply here? Or is that for questions about how to use ubiquity, rather than the after effects?

Comment: Dual-boot and partitioning usually would cover 90% to be honest. Most people either remove the Windows bootrec, or GRUB. In the case of Mac they can really mess things up, but those 2 tags should/would cover it as well. If they wanted to be specific they could add the other dual-boot OS. I don't see many people having troubles dual-booting 2 Linux systems.

Comment: Why not "data-recovery" and one of the Windows tags eg "Windows-8"? After all the goal is to recover Windows.

Comment: @unorthodoxgrammar that's the plan. For some reason people trough that "system-installation" was also relevant for question after the fact that you installed Ubuntu. [Those questions ain't about installing anything, and yet it had the tag.](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/9193/how-to-use-the-system-installation-tag?lq=1)