# How to use the "system-installation" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I didn't meant to lay rules about this tag, I presumed there will not be problems and the only one would be [software-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/software-installation)... apparently I was wrong.

When [I envisioned](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/7820/169736) the [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) tag, my thinking was that users interested in questions about "installing Ubuntu" would follow the tag and questions about the same topic would use it. This was reflected when I wrote my petition to separate the infamous [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation) in two tags:

> - [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation): For installations of Ubuntu. Remember that Ubiquity is the graphical installer of Ubuntu and questions about it should use also the [ubiquity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubiquity). This tag should be used for problems with the installation process itself and the use of the installer. Post/pre installations problems, ie. boot, dual-boot, partitioning schemes, have their own tags. The questions that fit from [installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/installation), i.e. **about installing Ubuntu itself.**

Now, what happened instead? A bunch of questions where the final goal is not about "installing Ubuntu" predates the tag instead:

- Lost windows xp data by installing 12.04, can I recover it? [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)
- How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu? [data-recovery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/data-recovery)
- Boot failure : No DEFAULT or UI configuration directive found! [boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/boot)
- [What do I have to do before giving away my Ubuntu machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34550/what-do-i-have-to-do-before-giving-away-my-ubuntu-machine) (this I wonder why the installation tag in first place) I'm temporally saying that "security" should be used, be my guess if you find something more useful.

Most of these questions is about problems post-installation. Things that happened after installing Ubuntu. Experts about installing Ubuntu may not know the answer to those questions, I mean, Ubuntu is already installed, what can an expert about doing what is already done tell you? What you did wrong? But isn't more useful how can I revert back?

These questions are of little interest to people that would potentially follow the tag and answer those questions.

So, I've said what should be not tagged with this, but what should?

- Install Ubuntu touch on Nexus? [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) [ubuntu-touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch)
- How I tell ubiquity that I want a LVM partition? [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) [ubiquity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubiquity) and maybe [lvm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lvm) if the question sways to LVM more than anything
- [USB drive install of Ubuntu 12.04 Server fails - can't find components from CD-ROM](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127398/usb-drive-install-of-ubuntu-12-04-server-fails-cant-find-components-from-cd-r) [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) and perhaps [debian-installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/debian-installer)
- Installing Ubuntu in a LXC container? [lxc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lxc) [system-installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/system-installation) (lxc takes precedence here)

As you can notice, the final goal is "installing Ubuntu" or problems found "while installing Ubuntu". Now there are some that are pre-installation that may use the tag but those are weird like "Should I leave an no assigned space before installing Ubuntu?" which the question is "should I do X before *installing Ubuntu*".

I hope this clears up some misunderstandings about the tag. If you have any edge case or doubt please ask, but as general rule "is about installing Ubuntu, us the tag" is pretty solid already.

Once this is agreed I would write an excerpt and tag wiki to reflect this.

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @NoTime beats me

Answer (score 2):

Misplaced tags happen.  I agree the way you have it is perfect and awesome in every way.  It points to a very specfic point in Ubuntus life on a PC.  Anything post install should not be allowed.  As a community it is also our job to clean up tags as nessicary.  If I see a question with a system-install tag(God forbid) on WINe, then it needs to be fixed to something.

On a side note does the order of tags have to matter?